# Couting how many times each option is selected in Select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I am working on a form to help someone do classroom observations.  The form has three main goals.

1. It needs to be all client side so I am using JavaScript.
2. It needs to keep track of the total number of intervals observed which I have accomplished.
3. It also needs to calculate how often each individual option is selected (Ex. How many times 1 is selected, how many times 2 is selected, etc.) This is where I am stuck. I feel like it should be a simple if statement and similar to my previous code that solved my first problem but I am having no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

In case it makes a difference there a total of 144 intervals.

Here is a sample of my form and the script that I have working that solved  my need #2.

My script

```
$('select[id*="interval"]').change(function() {
     total = 0;
    $('select[id*="interval"]').each(function() {
        total += (+this.value);
    });
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total;
});
```

Bits of my form

Where the script results print

```
<td><label>Total # Of Observation Intervals:</label></td><td><span id="result">0</span></td>
```

Where I want the options to be totaled

```
<tr>
<td><label>1. Lying Down:</label></td><td><span id="resultA">0</span></td><td>%</td>
<td><label>2. Sitting:</label></td><td><span id="resultB">0</span></td><td>%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>3. Standing:</label></td><td><span id="resultC">0</span></td><td>%</td>
<td><label>4. Walking:</label></td><td><span id="resultD">0</span></td><td>%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>5. Very Active:</label></td><td><span id="resultE">0</span></td><td>%</td>
</tr>
```

A couple of my dropdowns

```
<td><label class=select>Interval 1</label></td><td>Student Activity</td><td><select data-mini=true id="interval1">
<option value=0></option>
<option value=1 id="optA">1</option>
<option value=1 id="optB">2</option>
<option value=1 id="optC">3</option>
<option value=1 id="optD">4</option>
<option value=1 id="optE">5</option>
<option value=1 id="optF">6</option>
</select>
</td>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for=select-choice-4 class=select>Interval 2</label></td><td>Student Activity</td><td><select data-mini=true id="interval2">
<option value=0></option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=1>2</option>
<option value=1>3</option>
<option value=1>4</option>
<option value=1>5</option>
<option value=1>6</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Something I tried that did not work

```
$('select[id*="interval"]').options[1].value.change(function() {
            totalA = 0;
            $('select[id*="interval"]').options[1].value.each(function()  {
                totalA += (+this.value);
            });
            document.getElementById('resultA').innerHTML = totalA;
        });
```

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)...

Comment: when you say you are doing classroom observations, are you wanting to collate all the results from each pupil, if so using js won't work as it will only store the results per computer and that is only if the user doesn't hit refresh at the end

Comment: I mean, I am taking a paper form an administrator uses when they walk into a room and transferring it to an electronic version. So they observe 12 students basically 12 times each and the administrator records their result. In the past they have transferred the form to a spreadsheet and I am trying to get it to where the form does their totals as they click through the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly: Is the total variable defined somewhere outside the change(function(){}) scope? It should be.

Secondly: what your code does is - whenever each select changes, the first thing that it does is setting the total to 0 - no wonder why the total is wrong.

Thirdly: make sure you understand what $().each and $().change do, cause the whole program flow seems to be flawed

Moreover: you shouldn't have a similar value repeated several times in the same select

I can't understand what's your goal exactly, but this code here accomplishes something similar:

```
    var totals = { //totals
            interval1: {
                optionA: 0,
                //...
                optionZ: 0
            },
            interval2: {
                optionA: 0, //total hits for: <select id="interval2"> <option value="optionA">
                optionB: 0,
                optionC: 0
            }
            //etc...
    };

    $('select[id*="interval"]').each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){ //attach onchange event to each of the selects
            var $s = $(this);
            if(totals[$s.attr('id')]){
                totals[$s.attr('id')][$s.val()] += 1;
                //update the span corresponding to the particular select and the particular option value:
                $('#result_for_' + $s.attr('id') + '_' + $s.val()).text(totals[$s.attr('id')][$s.val()]);
            }
        })
    });
```

This is a solution that bases on **unique value** of each option (per select, they can repeat across selects)

This solution is also not optimal - you shouldn't search the DOM for $('#result_for_' + ....) everytime you want to update it. You should remember all the counters instead.

Good luck!

Comment: on the topic of the unique option value: think of a select as if it was a text input that is constrained to only a couple of options, the value of the selected option is the value of the select, just as the value you write down to an input would be the input's value

Comment: This all makes sense and is a huge help. As far as my goal, I am needing to track the number of questions answered and the # of times each answer chosen, Ex. how many times A, B, Or C are chosen. As far as the values all being 1, the short answer is I was thinking in terms of addition so I figured each option would basically need to count as one point.  I also think part of my issue was I am thinking of this as two separate problems, add up the # of questions, then go back and figure out how to track the answers. All that to say, I obviously got in over my head but thank you for all the help.